# Cancel Long Running Entity Framework 6 async requests

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, asynchronous

I'm using Entity Framework 6 (`DbContext`) in a WPF application, and I'd like to find a way to properly cancel the `async` data load methods (`ToListAsync` & `FirstOrDefaultAsync`) so I can immediately start another request.

I've been trying to stick with the single context per form (tab in my case) standard, and so far, I've been dealing with the non-thread safe nature of these calls by ensuring that the UI is disabled during requests, so the user can't start any new requests while one's in progress. However, I've run into a use case now where this is just not possible. I need to keep the UI responsive during some long-running requests, and in order to do that, I need a way to cancel the current request and start another one right away.

I've tried leveraging the `CancellationToken` support that was added to the `Async` methods, but I've found that when I cancel the request, it doesn't actually cancel anything. It will properly throw the `OperationCanceledException`, but the request is still in progress, and when I try to make another request after that, I still get `NotSupportedException (A second operation started on this context...)`

I'm using change-tracking, so changing the app to use a new Context for every request is not realistic.

Also, I've temporarily gotten around the issue by disposing the current context and creating a new one every time this particular view model makes a request while one's already in progress. This technically solves my issue, but I'm wondering if there's a way to do it while staying with the same context.

So, does anyone have any experience with this? I find it hard to believe I'm the first one who's run into this issue, but all other answers I've found on here for similar questions either recommend I use the `CancellationToken` (which doesn't work properly) or are a bit older and don't apply to the `Async` methods.

**EDIT 1:**

Since no one's answered this yet, I'm really starting to wonder what my options are here. A bit of background. I'm converting a Silverlight application to WPF.The Silverlight application was using WCF RIA services with EF 4.1, but with the WPF application, we decided to just use EF6.1.

With Silverlight & WCF, there is no limit to the number of async calls you can make at time, and we actually have a single context for the entire application (bad, I know, but simple and we never had any issues). We just bind directly to the entities, and use change-tracking to save the changes made by the user.

Is there just no way to do this in WPF, using EF 6.1 and the `Async` methods, in a real world application, where sometimes, you just need to cancel what the app is in the progress of doing and do what the user wants, without crashing and burning?

Comment: Can you please share the code in how you're using the cancellation token (where you're passing it to the query and how your triggering it)?

Comment: I've deleted it at this point, but what I had was that the View Model instantiated a new CancellationTokenSource. It would then pass in the CancellationToken to the ToListAsync, FirstOrDefaultAsync, and SaveChangesAsync methods. When needed, the VM would call Cancel on the CancallationTokenSource, and the code in the VM that made the request(s) was surrounded in a try catch that handled the OperationCanceledException.

Comment: There is "no" way to cancel the actual query against the database once it's sent aside from a sql connection or timeout of the transaction level. You might also make sure you call "ThrowIfCancellationRequested" to ensure that OperationCancelledException gets thrown after SaveChangesAsync or ToListAsync. I put "no" in quotes because I suppose you could at the db-level kill the spid of the running process which would then force a rollback of the transaction, but it's still going to run until the rollback is complete.

Comment: The exception was definitely being thrown by the EF async methods. I put in some logs, and I'd get something along the lines of:
17:50:57:028 [DEBUG] GetListAsync requested
17:50:58:032 [DEBUG] Cancel requested
17:50:58:160 [DEBUG] OpeationCanceledException caught
17:50:59:028 [DEBUG] GetListAsync response: ..

Answer (score 0):

Posting my solution for now. I'm not a huge fan, but it's all I've been able to get to work that wouldn't require completely rewriting this application from scratch.

I'm now using the `AsyncLock` class from [AsyncEx](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx) in repository methods that are accessing or saving tracked entities. Each of the DbContext objects use their own lock, so I'm not blocking other calls from other contexts or for untracked entities.

As an example, my GetListAsync method in my repository:

```
public async virtual Task<IList<T>> GetListAsync(IDbContext context,
                                                 Expression<Func<T, bool>> where,
                                                 IOrderByClause<T>[] orderBy = null,
                                                 params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] navigationProperties)
{
    using (await context.ContextLock.LockAsync())
    {
        IList<T> list = await GetListQuery(context, where, orderBy, navigationProperties).ToListAsync();
        return list;
    }
}
```

GetListQuery creates the query using the nav properties and where and order by clauses.

I'll probably also add a timeout as well, using a CancellationToken.